# Which enemies carry explosives that can be blown up with Fuse?

Tags: xcom-2

The psi-operative has an ability called Fuse which can prematurely detonate an enemy's explosives. As you can imagine this makes my inner child giggle with evil glee. However, it would help to know some further details.

- WHICH enemies carry explosives for targeting?
- Do those enemies have a chance to be equipped with an explosive, or do they always carry them?
- Can they carry more than one explosive, and if so, do they all cook off at once, or do they have to be Fused one by one? (Even if this isn't relevant to enemies in singleplayer, I'm almost certain it will be in  multiplayer with grenadiers)

Comment: Anecdotally, Mutons and MEC/Heavy MECs carry explosives with them evidenced if you try to mind control them. Archons too, but not sure if that works with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avent Troopers and Officers, both Advent Mec, Mutons, and Andromedon

Also you can fuse nades on dead bodies

[Edit]

The wiki indicates that Troopers and Mutons always have nades http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/ADVENT_Trooper

http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Muton_(XCOM_2)

Comment: Any reason/source why you assume that Advent Troopers and Mutons do not always carry a grenade?

Comment: I believe one of the monthly events causes basic advent troopers to carry one.

Comment: The [XCOM Wiki](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/ADVENT_Trooper) seems to indicate that Advanced and Elite Troopers always carry a grenade, while the basic Trooper does not. I am not aware of (dark?) event you mention.

Comment: cool, I'll update the answer, at the time I didn't have many troopers in my missions.